# Empty RELIES_ON for RESULT_CACHE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a query inside the function with RESULT_CACHE.

So when the table is changed - my cache is invalidated and function is executed again.

What I want is to implement the function that depends **only** on input parameters, and doesn't depend on any implicit dependencies (like tables, etc).

Is it possible (without dynamic sql)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a function that depends only on its parameters can be declared DETERMINISTIC. The results of this function will be cached in some cases. This [thread on the OTN forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2145402) shows how deterministic function results get cached inside SQL statements.

As of 10gR2, the function results don't get cached across SQL statements nor do they get cached in PL/SQL. Still, this cache feature can be useful if you call a function in a SELECT where it might get called lots of time.

I don't have a 11gR2 instance available right now, so I can't test the RESULT_CACHE feature, but have you considered delaring your function relying on a fixed dummy table (a table that never gets updated for instance)?

Comment: Yep, I tried to specify RELIES_ON to some another table, but oracle is smart enough to see that I was cheating :-S Well `DETERMINISTIC` looks exactly what I want. Will check it on my next working day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is NO.
A solution in cases where things like result caches and materialized views won't work because of invalidations or too much overhead is the Oracle In-Memory Database Cache option. See [result caches ..... what about heavily modified data](http://ronr.blogspot.com/2011/04/result-caches-what-about-heavily.html) It's a real smart option, not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a database link it is possible to create a function result cache that will read from a table when a parameter changes but will not be invalidated when the table changes.

Obviously there are some issues with this approach; performance (even for a self-link), maintenance, the function may return the wrong result, everybody hates database links, etc.

Note that RELIES_ON is deprecated in 11gR2.  Dependencies are automatically determined at run-time, even dynamic SQL wouldn't help you here.  But apparently this dependency tracking doesn't work over database links.

The script below demonstrates how this works.  Remove "@myself" from the function to see how it normally works.  Some of the code is based on [this great article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=504).

```
--For testing, create a package that will hold a counter.
create or replace package counter is
    procedure reset;
    procedure increment;
    function get_counter return number;
end;
/

create or replace package body counter as
    v_counter number := 0;
    procedure reset is begin v_counter := 0; end;
    procedure increment is begin v_counter := v_counter + 1; end;
    function get_counter return number is begin return v_counter; end;
end;
/

--Create database link
create database link myself connect to <username> identified by "<password>"
using '<connect string>';

drop table test purge;
create table test(a number primary key, b varchar2(100));
insert into test values(1, 'old value1');
insert into test values(2, 'old value2');
commit;

--Cached function that references a table and keeps track of the number of executions.
drop function test_cache;
create or replace function test_cache(p_a number) return varchar2 result_cache is
    v_result varchar2(100);
begin
    counter.increment;
    select b into v_result from test@myself where a = p_a;
    return v_result;
end;
/

--Reset
begin
    counter.reset;
end;
/

--Start with 0 calls
select counter.get_counter from dual;

--First result is "value 1", is only called once no matter how many times it runs.
select test_cache(1) from dual;
select test_cache(1) from dual;
select test_cache(1) from dual;
select counter.get_counter from dual;

--Call for another parameter, counter only increments by 1.
select test_cache(2) from dual;
select test_cache(2) from dual;
select test_cache(2) from dual;
select counter.get_counter from dual;

--Now change the table.  This normally would invalidate the cache.
update test set b = 'new value1' where a = 1;
update test set b = 'new value2' where a = 2;
commit;

--Table was changed, but old values are still used.  Counter was not incremented.
select test_cache(1) from dual;
select test_cache(2) from dual;
select counter.get_counter from dual;

--The function is not dependent on the table.
SELECT ro.id           AS result_cache_id
,      ro.name         AS result_name
,      do.object_name
FROM   v$result_cache_objects    ro
,      v$result_cache_dependency rd
,      dba_objects               do
WHERE  ro.id = rd.result_id
AND    rd.object_no = do.object_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Don't query any table.
2. Implement your own cache - wrap the function in a package, and store the query results in a PL/SQL table in memory. The downside to this approach, however, is that the cache only works within a single session. Each session will maintain its own cache.

Comment: Well, as a 9k user you should understand that it is not an answer ;-) I expect as answer some option that changes behaviour to the needed one, or simply "No". (anyway, +1 for writing alternatives (which I don't like though))

Comment: @zerkms Nice nested parenthesis there :)

Comment: Well, as a 22k user you should understand that in this case, "No" is not strictly the correct answer... :) - plus, I think this answer might be helpful to someone who comes along later.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: hehe, ok ;-) (btw, "no" is still a good answer, at least i think so)

Comment: Well, not really - you asked "is it possible to implement a function that depends only on input parameters" and the answer is Yes :)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: obviously I asked that in the context of RESULT_CACHE feature, otherwise I hadn't specified it in the question ;-) Is it possible with `result_cache`? Still "yes"?

Comment: Well, RESULT_CACHE is not limited to just queries on tables, isn't it? You can have a result cache on the return result of any function, and it will work as long as the function is deterministic.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: it is not limited indeed, but in my question I specified that I do have a query ;-)