# Oracle 10G search views, jobs, procedures for text string

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Our Oracle DBLink is changing and I need to search for references to the old location so that we can update them to point to the new location.  I need to be able to search views, procedures, jobs, the whole nine yards.  There are just too many views and to look at each one, one at a time.

Using TOAD or SQL Developer, how can I query the database for string text?  I have found queries that will allow me to search for objects but I need to search deeper than that.

TIA

Oracle 10G

Comment: Can you keep same DB_LINK name and just change HOST to point to new location? This way you don' have to change any objects using this reference.

Comment: @rs Can you explain a bit more about your suggestion or is it that straight forward?

Comment: Try to run this sql -  `select * from DBA_DB_LINKS;` You'll see that `DB_LINK` column is name/reference to host. If you update `HOST` column value you don't have to change `DB_LINK` used in your queries.

Comment: I can run this and did get some results back.  I confirmed with the team lead and the dblink name will stay the same and point to the new location. We need to test to confirm that nothing breaks after the update.  We still need to be able to identify the applications that reference the link so that we can test them thoroughly after the update.

Comment: Try this to get list of all dependencies `select * FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES WHERE REFERENCED_LINK_NAME = 'DB_LINK_HERE' order by name;`

Comment: @rs. That query would help, but may not capture all dependencies.  At least dynamic SQL would not show up, and possibly some other scenarios.  Dependencies for database links are not always tracked very well.  For example, in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6197110/409172) I used database links specifically to avoid a dependency.  Although that example actually does show up in DBA_DEPENDENCIES, it wouldn't surprise me if there are other cases where it does not.

Comment: @jonearles, you are right about dependencies, to find any in  dynamic sql we can use USER_SOURCE table - `select * from USER_SOURCE where upper(text) like '%DB_LINK_HERE%';`

Answer (score 3):

Procedures and jobs are relatively easy to search:

```
select * from dba_source where upper(text) like '%@MY_LINK%';
select * from dba_jobs where upper(what) like '%@MY_LINK%';
select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where upper(job_action) like '%@MY_LINK%';
```

But views are difficult:

```
select * from dba_views where upper(text) like '%@MY_LINK%';
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG
```

There are several ways to use LONGs.  The simplest would be to use PL/SQL, and select each each text `...into v_varchar2_32767...`.  But that method is not very easy to modify.

You may want to look into the [Dictionary Long Application](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430#c05bc), that converts LONGs into CLOBs.  Then you could use a query like this:

```
select *
from table(dla_pkg.query_view('select * from dba_views'))
where upper(text) like '%@MY_LINK%';
```